# How can I print enum in C?

Tags: c, enums

I have such `enum constuct` and `typedef struct`:

```
#define str(x) #x

typedef enum {
    MCSIMULATION,
} jobType;

typedef struct {
    jobType type;
}x, *xPtr;

int main(){
    xPtr f = malloc(sizeof(x));
    f->type = MCSIMULATION;
    return 0;
}
```

Then I want to print the value of `f.type`:

```
printf("%s", str(f->type));
```

But as output I have, when I expected to have "MCSIMULATION":

```
f->type
```

How to print it properly?

Comment: Try using printf("%d", f->type);

Comment: @user3351949 then the whole point of having `MCSIMULATION` is lost, nop?

Comment: @user3351949 I will have 0, but I want to have a string value of enum.

Comment: @SouravGhosh The desired output is "MCSIMULATION" ?

Comment: @SouravGhosh Sorry didn't get the Question